# conntrack delete does not stop runnig copy of big file

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat, conntrack

I have a router with nat port forwarding configured. I launched a http copy of big file via the nat. The http server is hosted on the LAN PC which contains the big file to download. I launched the file download from WAN PC.
I disabled the nat rule when file copy is running. the copy of file keep remaining. I want to stop the copy of file when I disable the nat forward rule with conntrack-tool.

[image]

my conntrack list contains the following conntrack session

```
# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
tcp      6 431988 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 [ASSURED] use=1
```

I tried to remove it with the following command:

```
# conntrack -D --orig-src 192.168.33.13
tcp      6 431982 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 [ASSURED] use=1
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been deleted.
```

the conntrack session is removed I can see in the following command. But another conntrack session was created with src ip address is the lan address of the removed conntrack

```
# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
tcp      6 431993 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 [ASSURED] use=1
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 57 flow entries have been shown.
```

I tried to remove the new conntrack but it keep remaining

```
# conntrack -D --orig-src 192.168.3.17

# conntrack -L | grep "33.13"
conntrack v1.4.3 (conntrack-tools): 11 flow entries have been shown.
tcp      6 431981 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.3.17 dst=192.168.33.13 sport=80 dport=52722 src=192.168.33.13 dst=192.168.33.215 sport=52722 dport=80 [ASSURED] use=1
```

What I m missing?

Comment: How did you remove the nat rule ? Can you post `iptables-save` output ? (or `iptables -nL -t nat`)

Comment: @bocian85 It's not iptables issue. In fact disabling iptables rule will not affect existing connection. It will affect future connections. and that's what happening for me. the current copy keep remaining but I can't make new copy any more

Comment: I know but i just wanted to confirm that NAT is truly disabled

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt

> `nf_conntrack_tcp_loose - BOOLEAN
>
>       0 - disabled
>       not 0 - enabled (default)
>
>       If it is set to zero, we disable picking up already established
>       connections.`

So the already established connection is detected on-the-fly (without SYN/SYN+ACK/ACK involved) and added back as a new conntrack entry. Since it's a new conntrack entry, the nat table will be traversed again and the DNAT rule applied again. Even if one way doesn't work immediately (if there's no SNAT/MASQUERADE defined in addition to the DNAT rule the http server's outgoing packets might appear on WAN as 192.168.3.17 for a short while and be rejected/ignored by 192.168.33.13), as soon as the other way tries again (ACK retry from 192.168.33.13...) this will match.

Type this:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_loose
```

And try again deleting the conntrack entry with `conntrack -D` ...

This should hopefully prevent a new conntrack entry to be created and cut the download.

**This answer is copied from:** https://superuser.com/questions/1258689/conntrack-delete-does-not-stop-runnig-copy-of-big-file